# Calculate a limit of probability

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory

Assume $ \left(X_{k}\right)_{k} $ is a sequence of independent random variables with distribution $ Ber\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) $ (all of them).

Calculate the limit:

$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}[\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+X_{k}\right)\leq a^{n}] $

for any $ a\geq 1 \in \mathbb {R} $.

Here's what I've tried:

$ \mathbb{P}[\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+X_{k}\right)\leq a^{n}]=\mathbb{P}[\ln\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+X_{k}\right)\leq n\ln a\right) $

$ =\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln\left(1+X_{k}\right)\leq n\ln a\right) $

$ =\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\ln\left(1+X_{k}\right)}{\ln2}\leq\frac{n\ln a}{\ln2}\right) $

Now notice that each $ \frac{\ln\left(1+X_{k}\right)}{\ln2} $ distributed $ Ber(1/2) $, and also it is the sum of independent random variables (as measurable functions of independent random variables), so the sum is distributed $ Bin(n,1/2) $. Thus:

Note that if $ a>2 $ then the probability would just be $ 1 $, so im gonna assume $ 1<a<2$.

$ \mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\ln\left(1+X_{k}\right)}{\ln2}\leq\frac{n\ln a}{\ln2}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor n\frac{\ln a}{\ln2}\right\rfloor }\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-k}=\frac{1}{2^{n}}\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor n\frac{\ln a}{\ln2}\right\rfloor }\binom{n}{k} $

All I have left to do now is to calcualte

$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}}\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor n\frac{\ln a}{\ln2}\right\rfloor }\binom{n}{k}$

Which I dont know how.

Any ideas would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$Y_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n, 1/2).$$  Then it is obvious that $$\prod_{k=1}^n (1 + X_k) = 2^{Y_n}.$$  So $$\Pr[2^{Y_n} \le a^n] = \Pr\left[Y_n \le n \frac{\log a}{\log 2}\right] = \Pr\left[\frac{Y_n - n/2}{\sqrt{n/4}} \le (2c - 1) \sqrt{n}\right],$$ where $c = \frac{\log a}{\log 2}$.  Then as $n \to \infty$, by the central limit theorem, $(Y_n - n/2)/\sqrt{n/4}$ tends to a standard normal distribution.  Consequently the desired probability is $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \Pr[2^{Y_n} \le a^n] = \begin{cases} 0, & a < \sqrt{2} \\ 1/2, & a = \sqrt{2} \\ 1, & a > \sqrt{2}. \end{cases}$$

Comment: Why is it obvious that the multipication equals $ 2^{Y_n} $ ?

Comment: @FreeZe Because for each $k$, the random variable $1 + X_k$ is $1$ if $X_k = 0$, and $2$ if $X_k = 1$.  So if $Y_n$ counts the number of $X_k$ that equal $1$, the product $$\prod_{k=1}^n (1 + X_k)$$ comprises exactly $Y_n$ factors of $2$; i.e., it equals $2^{Y_n}$.

Comment: In this situation: $ Pr[\frac{Y_{n}-\frac{n}{2}}{\sqrt{\frac{n}{4}}}\leq\left(2c-1\right)\sqrt{n}] $, how can you use the CLT?  I would understand if on the LFS you had some real number, but the variable of the limit appear there, so can you elaborate on how you take the limit?

Answer (score 0):

If you know SLLN you don't have to compute anything. $P(\frac 1n \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \ln (1+X_k) \leq \ln a) \to P(\ln (1+X_1) \leq \ln a)=P(\frac 1 2 ln 2 \leq \ln a)=0$ if $a <\sqrt 2$ and and lmit is $1$ if $a >\sqrt 2$. You can use CLT to show that the limit is $\frac 1 2$ if $a=\sqrt 2$.